# Why reducer action is carying twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

```
export const initialState = {
  ids: [],
  basket: [],
  subtotal: 0
}

const reducer = (state, action) => {

  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_TO_BASKET':
      debugger
      if (state.ids.indexOf(action.item.id) !== -1) {
// if not new item increase a quantity
 console.log(state.basket.find((el) => el.id.match(action.item.id)).quantity);
        ++state.basket.find((el) => el.id.match(action.item.id)).quantity;
        state.subtotal += action.amount

      }
      if (state.ids.indexOf(action.item.id) === -1) {
//if new value push id to array and push new value to basket
        state.ids.push(action.item.id)
        state.subtotal += action.amount
        state.basket = [...state.basket, action.item]

      }
      return {
        ...state,

      }

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

I've used the debugger and where time to increase quantity it worked twice,
if I change  `return { ...state  }` to `return state` all works right only one-time increase, but UI isn't refreshing (basket counter)

Comment: How is add to basket triggered?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky onClick

Comment: Okay sure but inside a form? Is the the button type submit and you have onClick on the button? Do you also have onSubmit? Having both can cause duplicate submissions

Comment: You're mutating state - `state.ids.push` mutates the array, don't do that. Also, the first argument in the reducer function should default to `initialState` - `const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => { ... }`

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky  <button onClick={addToBasket}>Add to Basket</button> only 1 button in Component, I havn't button OnSubmit

Comment: @Adam I think the problem in return, because if only `return state ` all good, but I need to refresh UI on page

Comment: `but I need to refresh UI on the page` - then it's obviously not all good. First rule of react (includes redux) - don't mutate state [last line on this page](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#state). EDIT: This may not fix your immediate problem, but mutating state will certainly lead to other extremely confusing bugs that you'll encounter later, so you might as well fix it while you're here.